# Flutter/Dart pass an argument in an array?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am trying to change a page in Flutter, here's my code:

```
class _RootAppState extends State<RootApp> {
  int tabIndex = 0;

  final pages = [
    Start(),
    Quiz(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      body: getBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget getBody() {
    return pages[tabIndex];
  }
}
```

and I thought I will create a constructor for `Start()` and `Quiz()` class to pass `tabIndex` argument because the other pages need this integer to be used for another change.

But passing an argument in an array gets me an error

```
The instance member 'tabIndex can’t be accessed in an initializer.
```

I can pass an argument in
`body: Start(tabIndex)`
But what if I wanted to do it in an array of my pages? Is this possible or should I look for another solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you refactor the initialization of `tabIndex` and `pages` to be handled by the constructor, then you should be able to initialize `pages` as described:

```dart
class RootApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const RootApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RootAppState createState() => _RootAppState();
}

class _RootAppState extends State<RootApp> {
  _RootAppState({this.tabIndex = 0})
      : pages = [
          Start(tabIndex: tabIndex),
          Quiz(tabIndex: tabIndex),
        ];

  int tabIndex;

  final List<Widget> pages;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      body: getBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget getBody() {
    return pages[tabIndex];
  }
}

class Start extends StatelessWidget {
  const Start({Key? key, required this.tabIndex}) : super(key: key);
  final int tabIndex;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text('Start Placeholder $tabIndex');
}

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  const Quiz({Key? key, required this.tabIndex}) : super(key: key);
  final int tabIndex;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text('Quiz Placeholder $tabIndex');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that `Start()` and `Quiz()` are `Widget`
But maybe you should take a closer look at [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html).